# Rolling temporal window on a pandas dataframe by group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider this example dataframe (code for construction below):

```
             t    p
o                   
2007-01-01  0.0  1.0
2007-01-02  0.0  1.0
2007-01-03  0.0  1.0
2007-01-10  0.0  1.0
2007-01-11  0.0  1.0
2007-01-20  1.0  0.0
2007-01-21  1.0  0.0
2007-01-22  1.0  0.0
2007-01-23  1.0  0.0
2007-01-27  1.0  0.0
```

I would like a rolling sum over a 2 day **forward-looking** window, for each 'group' in `t`. To do this I implemented:

```
df.iloc[::-1].groupby('t').rolling(window='2D').sum()
```

However, this returns:

```
                 t    p
 t      o                   
0.0 2007-01-11  0.0  1.0
    2007-01-10  0.0  2.0
    2007-01-03  0.0  3.0
    2007-01-02  0.0  4.0
    2007-01-01  0.0  5.0
1.0 2007-01-27  1.0  0.0
    2007-01-23  2.0  0.0
    2007-01-22  3.0  0.0
    2007-01-21  4.0  0.0
    2007-01-20  5.0  0.0
```

which is not a two day rolling window sum. I believe the issue is when I groupby `t` I lose the temporal information ('o') as it is set as the dataframes index.

Resampling the rows to constant 1 day intervals per group will not work due to the size of my dataframe. I have tried grouping by 't' then 'o' but this does not work.

The solution I would like is:

```
             t    p
    o                   
2007-01-01  0.0  2.0
2007-01-02  0.0  1.0
2007-01-03  0.0  0.0
2007-01-10  0.0  1.0
2007-01-11  0.0  0.0
2007-01-20  2.0  0.0
2007-01-21  2.0  0.0
2007-01-22  1.0  0.0
2007-01-23  0.0  0.0
2007-01-27  0.0  0.0
```

**Supplementary code:**

```
# code to construct df used in this example
o = ['2007-01-01','2007-01-02','2007-01-03','2007-01-10','2007-01-11',
     '2007-01-20','2007-01-21','2007-01-22','2007-01-23','2007-01-27']
t = np.zeros(10)
p = np.ones(10)
p[5:] = 0
t[5:] = 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'o':o, 't':t, 'p':p})
df['o'] = pd.to_datetime(df['o'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('o')
```

Comment: Possibly related to this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13966

Comment: It works when dates are sorted and ascending

Comment: Ah, I guess it is to do with how it calculates the windows, when descending perhaps it sees a always sees a window less than 3 days because it calculates -X days. We'll have to look at the source code but I guess that's it

Comment: Ok, so the only problem I know have is how to get a *forward* looking window

Comment: So it looks like [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6772) hasn't been implemented. Would be interested in hearing a work around?

I am surprised as it seems a fairly common thing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around (for two days):

```
def day_shift(x, days=2):
    ret = pd.DataFrame(0, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    for day in range(-days, 0):
        ret = ret.add(x.shift(day, freq='D'), fill_value=0)

    return ret.reindex(x.index)

df.groupby('t', as_index=False).apply(day_shift, days=2)
```

Output:

```
              t    p
o                   
2007-01-01  0.0  2.0
2007-01-02  0.0  1.0
2007-01-03  0.0  0.0
2007-01-10  0.0  1.0
2007-01-11  0.0  0.0
2007-01-20  2.0  0.0
2007-01-21  2.0  0.0
2007-01-22  1.0  0.0
2007-01-23  0.0  0.0
2007-01-27  0.0  0.0
```

---

**Edit**: Another way to exploit the rolling date is to reverse the date index, then we can use backward rolling, which is actually forward rolling in terms of the original dates:

```
future_date = pd.to_datetime('2100-01-01')
ancient_date = pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01')

# instead of setting `'o'` as index, let set ['o','t'] as index
df = df.set_index(['o','t'])

# here comes the crazy code
(df
    .assign(r_dates = (future_date - df.index.get_level_values('o')) + ancient_date)  # reverse date
    .sort_values('r_dates')
    .groupby('t')
    .rolling('2D', on='r_dates').sum()    # change 2 to the actual number of days
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)      # remove the index caused by groupby
    .assign(r_dates = lambda x: (x.index.get_level_values('o') - pd.to_timedelta('1D')), # shifted the date by one, since rolling includes the current date
           )
    .reset_index()
    .drop('o', axis=1)
    .set_index(['r_dates','t'])
    .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
                  p
o          t       
2007-01-01 0.0  2.0
2007-01-02 0.0  1.0
2007-01-03 0.0  0.0
2007-01-10 0.0  1.0
2007-01-11 0.0  0.0
2007-01-01 1.0  0.0
2007-01-02 1.0  0.0
2007-01-03 1.0  0.0
2007-01-10 1.0  0.0
2007-01-11 1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Ok, this looks very promising. I don't understand how it works yet but can it be made more general? i.e., to work for a window of any size of days???

Comment: That's amazing thanks, and appear quite robust. I'll have to check how fast it is on my actual data,  I imagine the for loop will slow things down. But it is an excellent solution thus far.

Comment: @FChm if the double loop `apply-for` is two slow on actual data, see the new solutions :-).

Comment: Thanks, just testing the current implementation. I imagine it will be too slow (I have 10 million rows), but will look at your over solution. pandas gurus always amaze me!

Comment: Back of the envelope calculation shows the original implementation will take 500 hours.. I'll try your second solution thanks :D

Comment: Currently the second solution raises the error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Which is a result of the final re-index operation.

Comment: I did notice that, but still getting an issue.

Comment: I see where the problem might be: You have overlapping dates across `t`. Better set both `t` and `o` as index. Let see if I can work around.

Comment: You are correct, this is just a smaller dataset. In reality, each 't' is a string and each string value can contain any date. Would if help if I updated my question to better reflect this?

Comment: I should add: I'm not actually interested in the sum of 't', just of 'p' - If that makes things easier.

Comment: So I aligned the two set of dates, then fixed the code. See updates.

Comment: That is phenomenal, 100 times speed up compared to the original answer. I still have a lot more to learn in pandas! Thanks very much for your efforts.